# iOS UITableView setBackgroundView with 2 subviews

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm running into a problem trying to perform a certain effect on iOS with tableviews...I know this can be done with normal UIViewControllers, but can't seem to pull it off with UITableViewControllers.

The effect is showing a clear background image behind a tableview and and as the user scrolls down the tableview, the background blurs. No problem getting that to happen.

The issue I'm having is that using a UITableViewController, I can only seem to have 1 ImageView behind the TableView and to create the blurring effect, the extension i am using will require 2 image views, one of which is the blurred image and has it's opacity set to 0 at launch.

This is code I know works using a UIViewController:

```
UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_004.png"];

self.backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
self.backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[self.view addSubview:self.backgroundImageView];

self.blurredImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
self.blurredImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
self.blurredImageView.alpha = 0;
[self.blurredImageView setImageToBlur:background blurRadius:10 completionBlock:nil];
[self.view addSubview:self.blurredImageView];
```

This is the code I am trying on the UITableViewController that does not work:

```
UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_004.png"];
self.backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
self.backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

[self.tableView setBackgroundView:self.backgroundImageView];

// Also tried this, to no success
[self.tableView.backgroundView addSubview:self.blurredBackgroundView];

self.blurredBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
self.blurredBackgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
self.blurredBackgroundView.alpha = 0;

[self.blurredBackgroundView setImageToBlur:background blurRadius:10 completionBlock:nil];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:self.blurredBackgroundView];

// Also tried this, to no success
[self.tableView.backgroundView addSubview:self.blurredBackgroundView];
```

If anyone has some suggestions how how to make this work, i'd love some advice. I really wouldn't like to change my code from a TableViewController to a UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

Set the table view's `backgroundView` property to point to an instance of `UIView`, and then add your image views as subviews of the new view. You can't directly add subviews to instances of `UIImageView`